# Action Script 3.0 insert a delay

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, delay

i'm new to AS and i'm trying to manage with some issue.

i'm having the next script

```
var t:Date = new Date ();
var day=t.getDate();
var month=t.getMonth()+1;
var today=day+"."+month;
var u:Number = 0;

var b_persons:Array = new Array ();

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("bday.xml"));
var bday_file:XML = new XML();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, endLoad);


function endLoad(all_data:Event)

{
   bday_file = XML(all_data.target.data);

   for each (var person:XML in bday_file.Person) 
   {
      if (person.BD == today) 
      {
          b_persons.push(person.FIO);

          trace (b_persons.length);
      }
   }
}

function assign_txtBdayPerson()
{
    txtBdayPerson.text=b_persons[u];
    trace(b_persons[u]);
    u=u+1;
    if (u >= b_persons.length)
    {clearInterval(delay_assign_txtBdayPerson);}

}

trace ("Test"+b_persons.length);

if (b_persons.length != 0)
    {
        var delay_assign_txtBdayPerson = setInterval(assign_txtBdayPerson,3000);
    }
```

my xml file has 2 suitable conditions, and the output window shows me the next sequence

Test 0  than    1 and last  2

so it seems that

```
trace ("Test"+b_persons.length);
```

runs earlier than

```
function endLoad(all_data:Event)
```

is completed

could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you want/need `trace ("Test"+b_persons.length);` to be run after XML has loaded and been been parsed, you will need to place it either within endload or inside a function that endload will call at the end of its function.

Events may seem different and evil if you are not used to them, but once you get used to them you will see they are much nicer to work with.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i did as you said, using multiple functions and the proper placement of this functions =)

events is realy interesting thing ... is there any event like "onfunction comleted" ? just interested =)

Comment: No, but you can dispatch your own custom events. `dispatchEvent(new Event("SomeFunctionFinished"));` at the end of the function. Just make sure you are listening to that event at the top `addEventListner("SomeFunctionFinished", _funcToCallWhenFinished`. but it would just be easier to call the function in the first place.

Comment: thanks, i've done othervise but everything new is good for me  =)

Answer (score 0):

It happens, because that `trace ("Test"+b_persons.length);` is executed in the same "frame" with the actual loading start. `endLoad()` callback is executed at least in the next frame, when the XML is already loaded. That is the nature of asynchronous flow in Flash.